# Get Assembly name from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stack-trace, .net-assembly

Currently I'm encountering the next problem: I have Locallization class which is static and specified in one of the assemblies in project(lets name it Proj.Common). And I have many plugins that are implementing some functionality. Each plugin is separate assembly that has it's own views. In order to localize message, I made function that gets plugin name via `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly.GetName().Name`.  But view are compiled to separate assemblies and therefore when view is calling localization class i have no idea what plugin has that view. How may I obtain the name of Calling assembly, not assembly where views are compiled. Thank You. And Yes, My application is made as MVC 2 ASP.Net application.

Comment: Have you tried getting the assembly name in the controller action, and passing it to the view via `ViewData`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new in MVC. How should I implement it? I need in my function getMessage(string name) get the name of assembly where view that called this function is placed,

Comment: I'm afraid you're on your own since you're using MVC 2.  I know a lot changed between 2 and 3, and I'm only familiar with 3 and 4.  All I can tell you is that you can get the assembly information in the controller's action method, and pass it to the view via `ViewData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the MVC objects in your function, you can call `ViewContext.Controller.GetType()`.

Comment: This provides me application assembly, not the plugin unfortunately.

Comment: What types does the plugin define?

Comment: Plugin is class that implements some functionality and is specified in it's own assembly. What is interesting, if you call the function from the plugin code, the result is correct.

Comment: @seeker: Can you access any types defined in the plugin? (eg, the model [from ViewContext], or something in the controller)

Comment: from function? No. Because the only argument in fuction is string that contains string to be localized.

Comment: Then you're stuck. If you can get the `ViewContext` (or `HtmlHelper`), you can probably find the plugin from that.

Comment: You may be able to muck around in `HttpContext.Current`; explore it in the debugger.